# Creating a Program that Dynamically Updates Itself

Tags: java, file-io, webserver, dynamic-data

I have a static java program that searches a folder for the most recently made file, parses the file for a few keywords, and then creates an organizational chart based on the keywords it finds.  How can I get this program to update(run) itself if a new file gets added to the folder?  Any tutorials that may be of help?  I'm pretty new to programming in general.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want the program to run again if a newer file is placed in a specific folder?

Comment: what you want to do?  do you want to excute the program automatically if any file modified in folder or do u want to update any part of the program if any change in folder?

Comment: What do you mean by program to update itself? maybe you want to design a program which reads all the contents of a folder or read the contents of a folder where filename matches a given criteria and then run the program again whenever a new file is added. Does that make sense?

Comment: I mean that I would like the program to run again if the folder is modified(has a new file put in it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably want the Java WatchService: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html

Tutorial here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html

Comment: Thank you this looks promising.  I will look into it.

Answer (score 1):

The two ways to do this that I am familiar with are the [JNotify Library](http://jnotify.sourceforge.net/) and the regular [event listener for a WatchService/WatchEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Java file watcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) to detect when new files are added to that directory. When you receive the event that a file has been added, you update your chart